# Will Page Rank affect if we delete index.php from URL?

Tags: url, seo, development

Suppose a website having page rank 3 and it contains index.php in all its urls like below and their page rank
www.xyz.com/index.php/about-us Page rank 2
www.xyz.com/index.php/services Page rank 2
.
.
and so on.
So if we remove "index.php" now, will it affect in SEO page rank and search results?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Not if you use a 301 redirect to redirect the /index.php/ URL's to the URL's w/o the index.php. You can do this using .htaccess, for example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Copied from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18777310/247515

Comment: Thanks for the reply but if you redirect all urls of the website using 301,I think it is not good for SEO.Because redirecting each every url with 301 is not good in the eyes of search engine.

Comment: @KaluCharan Not sure if the number of redirects matter - but anyway if you want to remove index.php this is the best way to do it.

Comment: According to Google, a 301 will attenuate PageRank inflow by ~15%, which is about the same as a normal link. Consequently where a link _and_ a 301 are in series, total PageRank loss is compounded. So in addition to the redirects Bjørn correctly suggests, you'd update your internal links to the new (sans index.php) format and ideally try to get key external links updated too, though some loss from external links is likely unavoidable. I'm not aware of any basis for idea that redirecting every URL is "not good in the eyes of search engine": doing so is standard practice when migrating sites.